# How can I import whole winform project from windows VS to Linux Mono?

Tags: c#, winforms, mono, monodevelop

I have a project. It includes a winnform project written in VS using C#. The project contains multiple forms and Camera SDK of Hikvision too. I want to import that project to Mono in Linux.

when I copied the .exe file of a simple HelloWorld winform app, it ran successfully in mono with the command `mono HelloWorld.exe` but with the large project it is showing errors:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: ..\\..\\..\\SDK\\Camera\\Hikvision\\HCNetSDK.dll assembly:<unknown 
assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) DCRS_UI_01_19.SDK.Hikvision.CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_Init()
  at DCRS_UI_01_19.SDK.Hikvision.HikvisionVarFunc..ctor () [0x0003f] in 
<542dcdfe661a4a0bb8f9b8399fda367a>:0
at DCRS_UI_01_19.Form1..ctor () [0x00393] in <542dcdfe661a4a0bb8f9b8399fda367a>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) DCRS_UI_01_19.Form1..ctor()
  at DCRS_UI_01_19.Program.Main () [0x0000e] in <542dcdfe661a4a0bb8f9b8399fda367a>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: 
..\\..\\..\\SDK\\Camera\\Hikvision\\HCNetSDK.dll assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> 
member:(null)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) DCRS_UI_01_19.SDK.Hikvision.CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_Init()
  at DCRS_UI_01_19.SDK.Hikvision.HikvisionVarFunc..ctor () [0x0003f] in 
<542dcdfe661a4a0bb8f9b8399fda367a>:0 
  at DCRS_UI_01_19.Form1..ctor () [0x00393] in <542dcdfe661a4a0bb8f9b8399fda367a>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) DCRS_UI_01_19.Form1..ctor()
  at DCRS_UI_01_19.Program.Main () [0x0000e] in <542dcdfe661a4a0bb8f9b8399fda367a>:0
```

Working from scratch in mono using GTK# is the last option for me.
I am using mono version 6. Ubuntu LTS 18.04 is installed in Windows [Hyper-V](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/about/) .
I did not import whole project. I just imported the `.exe`  file from windows. the error is shown in my post. How, actually should the project be imported? whole project or solution or .exe file? A simple `helloword` winform app worked when I imported just .exe file.

Comment: What issues did you run into importing your project into monodevelop? It's kind of obvious mono will have difficulties finding referenced assemblies from a native Windows .exe.

Comment: @Filburt I did not import whole project. I just imported the .exe file from windows. the error is shown in my post. How, actually should the project be imported? whole project or solution or .exe file? A simple helloword winform app worked when I imported just .exe file.

Comment: I think this might help you.[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64330395/how-can-i-import-whole-winform-project-from-windows-vs-to-linux-mono)

Comment: @Virtuall.Kingg that was not helpful

Comment: Look into [Porting Winforms Applications](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/porting-winforms-applications/) ... you will need to port your entire solution because otherwise you will always face the same error you encountered when running your app: It will be missing referenced components. Your reference to the Camera SDK could turn out to be a showstopper if it relies on something that isn't supported under mono.